# SurfaceView run method code

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I am trying to draw a 10x10 grid of alternating colors. in my run() method I have this

```
    int xinc = this.getWidth() / 10;
int yinc = this.getHeight() / 10;
Log.d("xinc - ", String.valueOf(xinc));
Log.d("yinc - ", String.valueOf(yinc));
int x1 = 0;
int y1 = 0;
int x2 = xinc;
int y2 = yinc;
boolean red = true;

for (int xx = 0; xx < 10; xx++) {

    for (int yy = 0; yy < 10; yy++) {

        if (red) {
            myPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            red = false;
        } else {
            myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            red = true;
        }
        c.drawRect(x1, y1, x2, y2, myPaint);
        y1 += yinc;
        y2 += yinc;

    }
    x1 += xinc;
    x2 += xinc;
}

holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

I get the first row of vertical alternative boxes but that is all. The rest of the screen stays white. Its as though the x1 and x2 variables are not incrementing and so the outer loop is making no impact. however I have confirmed they are by using logcat on those variables, they increase as expected. can anyone see what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to reset y1 and y2!
I think a simple
`y1 = 0;
y2 = yinc;`

before

`x1 += xinc;
x2 += xinc;`

should do it.

Comment: thanks man, i had just realized that, but hadnt yet figured out where i need to reset :P